# Differences and similarities between $\mathbb{R}^4$, $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, $T_p\mathbb{R}^4$, and $T_p\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$

Tags: spacetime, coordinate-systems

Consdier $\mathbb{R}^4$ with Cartesian coordinate and $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ with spacetime coordinates. Also consider their corresponding tangent spaces $T_p \mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, respectively.

I have two questions:

(1) Do $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ have the same vector space structure?

(2) Do $T_P\mathbb{R}^4$ and $T_p\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ have the same vector space structure?

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain me these relations. I don't really understand their similarities and differences.

Comment: Do you understand that “vector space structure” does not include a metric?

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, I do.

Comment: Well, the only difference between $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ is their metric.

Comment: @Ghoster You mean they have the same vector space structure but difference metric? What about their tangent spaces?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean. The same applies to their tangent spaces.

Comment: @Ghoster I got it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a four-dimensional Euclidean space, whose metric signature is (++++), whereas $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ is a four-dimensional Lorentzian space whose metric signature is either (+---) or (-+++). The same is true of their tangent spaces also.

Comment: Can you define all four sets/vector spaces/ metric spaces etc.? Without a clear definition this question is not well-defined.